# Generating pretty block matrices that include expanded detail in their blocks using Latex

Tags: tables

I'd like to achieve the following using Latex:

[image]

I'm open to still-better ways of formatting such block matrices. But the above is what I'm thinking towards, right now.

I'll be doing a lot of these and I'd like to beautify the stuff I've been posting before. Especially since directed graphs, column and row spaces, the left and right nullspaces, modified network analysis, and the Schur complement method can figure prominently in analysis.

I'm not very familiar with using `tikz` packages. But I'll learn more, if needed.

The following is an example of the above that I do ***not*** want to produce:

[image]

It's sad-looking and I'm hoping for something significantly better, more in the direction of the first image above.

Comment: Welcome to the site, but MathJax questions are off topic here. MathJax isn't actually LaTeX, although it uses some LaTeX syntax.

Comment: @AlanMunn Understood and I'm aware MathJax isn't Latex. I'm sorry to hear that I'll need to find another way to ask the question. Feel free to close it. (I'd like to keep it for a while, even closed, because of the work put into framing it [until I find another place to ask.]) Noted the MathJax Tag and felt that it gave me a pass. Oh, well. I'll try meta and see where it goes.

Comment: Honestly I doubt this can be done with MathJax. You'd probably be better off making the images with LaTeX and inserting them.

Comment: @AlanMunn If I change the question to remove MathJax, focus on Latex, and allow tikz, as well, would that make it more appropriate? I think you are probably right and I wouldn't mind some help with Latex for this.

Comment: @AlanMunn Hopefully, that's more in tune with your thoughts, those thoughts of others here, and the site generally. And an answer would still be very useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `nicematrix` package. It should possible to make what you want relatively painlessly.

Comment: @AlanMunn The question started out as MathJax but trimmed it back to Latex which actually changed the context for the question quite a bit and now means (because packages are now broadly allowed) I'll need to revisit that package and put more effort in to earn a right to ask this question in the newer, changed context. I'll update my question with my work product and the reason I'm still looking for better, at that time (should I still be looking.) I will say that a quick use of search tools has failed to find a table I approve of that uses nicematrix. Need to search more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution based on TeX primitives `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\hrule`, `\vrule`, `\halign`:

```
\newdimen\colw \colw=3.2em
\let\col\hbox
\def\bmkern{\ifx\col\hbox \kern.25\colw \fi}

\def\bmat#1#2{{\def\col{\hbox to\colw}\bbmat{#1}{#2}}}
\def\bbmat#1#2{\vbox{\everymath={\scriptstyle}
   \hrule width.5\colw 
   \hbox to.5\colw{\vrule \strut\hss$#1$\hss\vrule}
   \hrule
   \moveright\dimexpr.5\colw-.4pt\hbox{\vrule
      \vtop{\kern1ex
         \halign{&\col{\bmkern\hss$##$\hss\bmkern}\cr#2\crcr}
         \kern1ex\hrule}%
      \vrule
   }
}}
\def\hmat#1{\par
   \moveright 1.25\colw\vbox{\everymath={\scriptstyle} 
      \halign{&\hbox to\colw{\hss$##$\hss}\cr #1\crcr}}
   \nobreak\vskip-\baselineskip
}
    

\hmat{v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_{\rm out} && v_{\rm in} & v_{\rm gnd}}
\bbmat{A} {
\bmat{P}   {{1\over R_1} + sC_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
              -1                & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr
              0 & -sC_2 & {1\over R_2} + sC_2 & 0 \cr
              0  & 0 & -1 & 1 }
&
\bmat{Q^T} {-{1\over R_1} & -sC_1 \cr 
             0            &  0    \cr
             0            & -{1\over R_2} \cr
             0            & 0
}
\cr \noalign{\kern1ex}
\bmat{Q}   {-{1\over R_1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
            -sC_1 & 0 & -{1\over R_2} & 0 }
&
\bmat{R}   { 1\over R_1 & 0 \cr
             0 & {1\over R_2} + sC_1} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's nice. The resulting code is tight, readable, and I think I'll learn a lot studying it more. Again, thanks for the lesson! Only one tiny alignment detail (the bmat box is slightly left of where I'd place the drawn lines.) +1 and selected. (And there's a bug -- a missing & between a -1 and a 1.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `nicematrix`. All the rules are drawn by using the command `\Block` (provided by `nicematrix` and its key `draw`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,amstext}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{exterior-arraycolsep}
$\begin{NiceArray}{*{12}{c}}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
\Block[draw]{}{A} & & & v_1 & v_2 & v_3 & v_{\text{out}} & & & v_{\text{in}} & v_{\text{gnd}} & \\
& \Block[draw]{*-*}{}\\
&  & \Block[draw]{}{P} & & & & & & \Block[draw]{}{Q^T} \\
& & & \Block[draw]{4-4}{}\frac{1}{R_1} + sC_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & \Block[draw]{4-2}{} -\frac{1}{R_1} & -sC_1 \\
& & & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & & & 0 & 0 \\
& & & 0 & -sC_2 & \frac{1}{R_2}+sC_2 & 0 & & & 0 & -\frac{1}{R_2} \\
& & & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & & & 0 & 0 \\
\\
& & \Block[draw]{}{Q} & & & & & & \Block[draw]{}{R} \\
& & & \Block[draw]{2-4}{} -\frac{1}{R_1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & & & \Block[draw]{2-2}{} \frac{1}{R_1} & 0 \\
& & & -sC_1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{R_2} & 0 & & & 0 & \frac{1}{R_2}+sC_1 \\
\\
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I am very privileged to have received these two answers. Tested already and verified! +1 to you, as well. I will spend my time learning from both of these methods and my profound thanks to you, as well. +1 of course! (Added: Hmm. Some column width variations that I'll want to deal with. But that much I can usually do at my modest level.)